# download large pandas data frame as CVS file

Tags: django, csv, download, streaming

I am trying to use this Django reference [Streaming large CSV files][1]

[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files to download a pandas dataframe as csv file.

It requires a generator.

```
# Generate a sequence of rows. The range is based on the maximum number of
# rows that can be handled by a single sheet in most spreadsheet
# applications.
rows = (["Row {}".format(idx), str(idx)] for idx in range(65536))
```

if I have a dataframe called my_df (with 20 columns, and 10000 rows) .... how do I revise this logic to use my_df instead of generating numbers as in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv') # Format response as a CSV
filename = 'some_file_name.csv'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'# Name the CSV response
my_df.to_csv(response, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
return response
```

Comment: Thank you very much.   Saved my day

Comment: well I've had a shockingly bad day and this is probably the only thing I've actually managed to get right!